# Magento 2: CE integrated ElasticSearch 6 - Autocomplete

Tags: magento2.3, elasticsearch, autocomplete

Magento 2.3 Commerce comes with Elastic Search integration.
I want to know, if someone or is it possible to customized the autocomplete feature and be able to search for products and categories like it is nicely done in Smile Elastic Suite

example:

[image]

Thanks,
Ajmal